# How to delete the deley messages that has not been consumed?

Tags: rocketmq

I want to delete the sent deley message or modify the sent deley message expiration time.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the consume offset by RocketMQ DashBoard or command line `sh mqadmin resetOffsetByTime`,

```
sh mqadmin resetOffsetByTime -s timestamp -t topic -g group -n namesrv
```

Answer (score 0):

No way to do that since RocketMQ does not support a message deletion in api.

You may consider achieving your goal when consuming.

For example, maybe you can define a consumer group called DelayMessageAdjuster, in this consumer you can check if the delay message should be aborted and adjust. If the answer is yes, then just send another new delay messages and something like this. I am not sure if this can achieve your goal.